# Air burst when pouring from Keg

Tags: airlock, pressure

I'm running taprite dual regulator on 10lb bottle. Ever since I taped a 58l beside my 20l keg, I get CO2 bubbles in my beer line which creates an air burst every time I pour a beer.

Is it possible my 58l keg is forcing back pressure into my 20l keg and over carbonating it? I've tried everything to stop this air burst, and it only started when I taped the 58l beside it.

Comment: Can you provide some information about your setup? What temperature and serving pressure are you using? How much beer line, and what diameter? How are the two kegs connected to the manifold, through a manifold or a tee? Are there check valves in the gas lines? Did the 58 go in warm? What pressure should the 58 be at? Did you adjust the regulator pressure when you added the 58? When you say dual regulator, does that mean you can run two independent pressures? How is the 58 pouring?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to tune your serving lines.

Beer should be served at the pressure needed for it's co2 volumes at serving temp.

For example a beer at 2.5 volumes needs 12 PSI at 38°.

A Belgian at 3.5 volumes needs 22 psi at 38°.

Both have to have different beer line lengths to do this.

Beer lines will have a spec sheet from the maker that tells you how much psi each foot of line will hold back. The goal is to have about 1-2 psi at the tap.

Most 3/16 line will hold back 1psi per foot. Larger diameters have less psi.

So, for the 2.5 beer you need 10 feet of 3/16 line between the keg and tap for 2 psi at the tap. The 3.5 beer would need about 20 feet for the same pour speed.

http://www.kegerators.com/beer-line-calculator.php

Beer hack: To save on buying a lot of line for different styles you can get 3/16 line to hold back more psi per foot with weed wacker line. 
This is my beer gun line I've tuned for very slow fill with just 3 feet of beer line using two wacker lines inside. This will fill a 22oz bottle in about 30 seconds at 12 psi
[image: beer gun]

Edit: I had read your question wrong. Answer corrected.

Comment: The air/co2 lock is right at the coupler, and hose are coiled horizontal. Is it the coupler that is suppose to have the check valve? Should I replace it?